# Решил сделать калькулятор на джаве. Вроде всё нормально, но ответ в консоль не выводит

Tags: java

```
package com.company;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
        int b = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
        String c = new Scanner(System.in).next();
        oper(a, b, c);
    }
    public static void oper(int a, int b, String c){
        if (c == "+")
            System.out.println(a + b);
        else if (c == "-")
            System.out.println(a - b);
        else if (c == "*")
            System.out.println(a * b);
        else if (c == "/")
            System.out.println(a / b);

    }
    }
```

Comment: Если вам дали ответ, который решает вашу проблему, то примите его(нажав на галочку рядом с ним) и поставьте ему плюс

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы не правильно сравниваете строки, нужно так, через `equals`

```
public static void oper(int a, int b, String c) {
    if (c.equals("+")) {
        System.out.println(a + b);
    }
}
```

подробнее о сравнение строк, можно почитать например [тут](https://javarush.ru/groups/posts/equals-java-sravnenie-strok)

Comment: Спасибо большое!)

Comment: @inone не за что)